# org-ref "Unbalanced parentheses", 20306, 18248 error

Tags: debugging, org-ref

I am new to org-mode and I am learning to use it to replace markdown for academic writing.

`M-x org-ref` gave me this error: `org-ref  "Unbalanced parentheses", 20306, 18248 error`
What should I do about it?

---

The error seems to have something to do with my `.bib` file.

[image: when loading with emotional_literacy.bib]

It works with one `.bib` file, after validation, though not completely. But fails in another.

[image: error with thesis.bib]

The same error occurs when trying to validate that `.bib` file with `M-x bibtex-validate` under `bibtex-mode`.

Both files have been generated by `better-bibtex` in Zotero.

---

## Debugger:

When validating `thesis.bib`

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (scan-error "Unbalanced parentheses" 20306 182486)
  scan-sexps(20306 1)
  forward-sexp(1)
  bibtex-parse-field-string()
  bibtex-parse-field-text()
  bibtex-parse-association(bibtex-parse-field-name bibtex-parse-field-text)
  bibtex-parse-field()
  bibtex-valid-entry()
  bibtex-validate(nil)
  funcall-interactively(bibtex-validate nil)
  call-interactively(bibtex-validate record nil)
  command-execute(bibtex-validate record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "bibtex-validate" "bibtex-vali")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "bibtex-validate" "bibtex-vali")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

`toggle-debug` made no difference in `org-mode`.

Comment: could you provide some more details? How did you install org-ref, for example? what is the output of M-x org-ref-version?

Comment: @JohnKitchin I installed it through `M-x package-install`. org-ref version 1.1.1

Comment: This looks like you have a syntax error in your bibtex file. Probably if you open it, and type M-x bibtex-validate it might give you a hint of where the problem is. I guess there is a missing bracket somewhere. A common way to find that is to bisect the file, e.g. comment half of it out, and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: I am working with a simple .bib file with just 2 to 3 entries now. Still couldn't get `bib-ref` to work.

Comment: I would post this as an issue on the org-ref github repo and include the org file and bib file. https://github.com/jkitchin/org-ref/issues